# Basic Chemistry: Carbon Dioxide Formation Unsure about Reaction

Tags: redox, decomposition, carbon-dioxide

I have the following question description:

> Consider a gas composed of  $\ce{CO_2}$,  $\ce{CO}$,  $\ce{O_2}$ and  $\ce{O}$ with 1  $\ce{C}$ nuclei for every 2  $\ce{O}$
> nuclei.

I am trying to write the basic chemical reaction but am unsure it's correct. Thus far I have:

$\ce{CO_2}$ +  $\ce{O}$ =  $\ce{CO}$ +  $\ce{O_2}$

Is this the correct format? Pretty sure I have to balance but wanted to make sure I have the correct reaction before I do so. I am just not sure what to do with the extra $\ce{O}$ in the question description...

Comment: The question description states: "Reacting Gas Property Mixtures"

Comment: Your suggested solution does not have 1 carbon for every 2 oxygen. I suggest, instead, starting with just $\ce{CO2}$.

Comment: This would make sense: CO2 = CO + .5*O2. Just the dissociation of CO2. But I still have the O that needs to be considered.., which is throwing me off

Comment: This "question" makes no sense. Please give the complete context, and cite the source.

Comment: The confusion with the questions is stemming from the fact that 1. $\ce{O}$ gas doesn't exist in nature. 2. You haven't specified the full question, just some of the set up.

Answer (score 2):

If you start with $\ce{CO2}$, you could have one reaction that yields $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{O2}$, and another where $\ce{O2}$ dissociates:

$$\ce{2CO2(g) -> 2CO(g) + O2(g)}\tag{1}$$

$$\ce{O2(g) -> 2O(g)}\tag{2}$$

Then, you can combined these two in arbitrary ways, or like this with a variable $x$:

$$\ce{2CO2(g) -> 2CO(g) + (1-x) O2(g) + 2x O(g)}\tag{1+2 combined}$$